# Context free Grammar for x1#x2#...#xn

Tags: context-free

Design a Context-free grammar **(CFG)** for this language

[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts on this language? Have you made any progress constructing a grammar? Do you have any ideas at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the idea behind the grammar first consider the **Pushdown Automata** for this langugage: Non-deterministically choose either the beginning or any $\#$, push the string between the chosen position and the next $\#$ symbol. Again non-deterministically choose another $\#$ and start popping out the symbols in the stack if they match with the current symbol being read. If we reach the next $\#$ and the stack becomes empty, then we have found two positions $\exists i,j : x_i = x_j^R$, and hence the word is in the language.

*(I'll suggest you now to stop reading the answer and try writing the grammar on your own)*

**Grammar** (let $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$:
\begin{equation}
S \rightarrow A\#B|A\#B\#A\\
A \rightarrow aA | bA|\#A|\epsilon\\
B \rightarrow \#\#|aB'a|bB'b\\
B' \rightarrow aB'a|bB'b|\#A\#|\# 
\end{equation}

*It might be written more succinctly perhaps. You can try that.

Comment: I think it is true, But I'm not sure

Comment: I think you should try convincing yourself that it is indeed true. If you find out a mistake, leave a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following grammar:

```
S → A | B
A → aA | bA | ɛ
B → C | B#B
C → aCa | bCb | aDa | bDb
D → # | #B#
```

The first rule (S) basically says that our string can be anything (rule A) without any delimiting #'s, or will follow the ...$\#x\#...\#x^R\#$... pattern (rule B).

For rules B, C, and D, think about how some strings in the $L_1$ are derived, and how these derivations will eventually terminate.